# what is the addressing mode of dec with memory? (assembly x86)

Tags: assembly, x86

What is the addressing mode for the operations:

dec Z-2

mov bx, offset Z+3

? I could find most of the scenarios except this ones :/

thanks allot!

Comment: You can find descriptions of all available modes in the sections _"Operand addressing"_ and _"Specifying an offset"_ in Intel's Software Developer's Manual.

Comment: Direct offset. It depends on the assembler syntax convention, but for most it would have to be `[Z-2]`.

Answer (score 0):

The first instruction `dec Z-2` most probably uses a memory operand. I think however many assemblers would prefer something like `dec word [Z-2]`. Written this way the instruction decrements the word before label/variable Z.

The second instruction `mov bx,offset Z+3` uses an immediate operand whose value is 3 more than the address of the label/variable Z. It doesn't approach the memory whose address was calculated.